# create 2D from lines

Tags: java, matrix

I get a text file where the first line gives me the array size I want, columns and rows , while the other lines give me booleans . I have to build this matrix , but can create the array but do not know what I have to do so through the other file lines create the matrix me with booleans inside

```
example: 5
         true true true true false
         false false true true false
         false false false true true
         true true true true true
         true false false true true
```

I have done so far is :

```
private int nLinhasColunas;
private boolean matrix[][];

public void matriz(BufferedReader rede)throws IOException{

    nLinhasColunas = Integer.parseInt(rede.readLine());
    matrix = new boolean[nLinhasColunas][nLinhasColunas];
```

Grateful for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A scanner object can be created with the BUfferedReader as the input Stream. This Scanner can directly parse boolean values.

Check the following code:

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(rede);
    for(int i = 0; i<nLinhasColunas; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j< nLinhasColunas; j++){
            Boolean b = sc.nextBoolean();
            matrix[i][j] = b;
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you!but so it will pick up from the second line of the file and make the matrix in the order they are given the booleans ?

Comment: It will scan the boolean values in the order in which they occur in the file and assign it to the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to use the following idea:

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
int nLinhasColunas =Integer.parseInt(sc.next());
matrix = new boolean[nLinhasColunas][nLinhasColunas];
    for(int i=0;i<nLinhasColunas;i++)
       for(int j=0;j<nLinhasColunas;j++)
          {
          String s=sc.next();
          if(s.equals("true"))
           {
              matrix[i][j]=true;
           }
         else
          {
           matrix[i][j]=false;
           }
          }
```

Comment: thanks for the tip , but this idea I am not fetch the values ​​of booleans to text file ( from the second line)

Comment: thank you!  can you only explain why to use a scanner and do a equals ?

Answer (score 0):

#### Easy way

1. Read the file and get all lines
2. Get the first line and split by space to get the number of lines.
3. Create the bidimensional array.
4. Remove the first line ('example: 5') from the List.
5. Iterate over the lines. In each iteration, split the current line by space in order to get an array with the boolean words.
6. Iterate the array with the boolean words, convert the current word to boolean and append it to the matrix.

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("/path/to/ur/file"));
String firstLine = lines.get(0);
int size = Integer.valueOf(firstLine.split(" ")[1]); // get '5'
boolean[][] matrix = new boolean[size][size];
Lines.remove(0); // delete the first line

for(int i=0; i<lines.size(); i++) {
     String[] lineParts = lines.get(i).split(" ");
     for(int k=0; k<lineParts.length; k++) {
     matriz[i][k] = new Boolean(lineParts[k]);
    }
}

System.out.println(matrix);
```